# How can I send a empty value in Int field in Rest assured

Tags: rest-assured

I want to send empty value in int field

```
Feature file made:
Scenario: To send null values in the mandatory field and invalid block key

    Given Uses the token and makes block number payload with "<block_key>" <src_number> with "<field>"

    When Now calls the "BlockNumber" api using "post" http request

    Then Verify API call status to be <status> and "<errorMessage>"

Examples:
|block_key|src_number|status|errorMessage|field| 

|did||422|Invalid request body|did|
```

```
StepDefinition:
res = given().spec(requestSpecification()).body(data.blockNumber(block_key, src_number, did))
                    .relaxedHTTPSValidation();
```

Error coming:

```
io.cucumber.junit.UndefinedStepException: The step 'Uses the token and makes block number payload with "did"  with "did"' is undefined.
You can implement this step using the snippet(s) below:

@Given("Uses the token and makes block number payload with {string}  with {string}")
public void uses_the_token_and_makes_block_number_payload_with_with(String string, String string2) {
    // Write code here that turns the phrase above into concrete actions
    throw new io.cucumber.java.PendingException();
}
```

I sent null value but not working